# Counting number of zeroes returns wrong result

Tags: python

```
lst = [1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0]

count = 0

for i in lst:
    if lst[i] == 0:
        count = count + 1;

print(count) #2
print(lst.count(0)) #3
```

why does the for loop not count the number of zeroes correctly

Comment: `i` is already an element of `lst`, so your condition must be `if i == 0:`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not iterating over indexes, but over elements of the array.

In `i`, you already have single elements of the array, not its indexes.

So, you can check for zeros just like this:

```py
lst = [1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0]

count = 0

for i in lst:
    if i == 0:
        count = count + 1;

print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
for i in lst:
   print(i)
```

will give you 1 0 2 3 0 4 5 0.
It gives you the content of the list and not the index (0, 1, 2, 3,...).

Answer (score 0):

Use condition `i==0` instead of `lst[i] == 0`

```
lst = [1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0]

count = 0

for i in lst:
    if i == 0:
        count = count + 1;

print(count) #3
print(lst.count(0)) #3
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing `count = count + 1` to `count += 1` and `i` is already in `lst` so the condition is `i==0` like this:

```
lst = [1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0]

count = 0

for i in lst:
    if i == 0:
        count += 1
    else:         # I think this condition has to be here as well
        print(i)

print(count) #2
print(lst.count(0)) #3
```